# MySQL Table Locking Advise

Tags: php, mysql, locking

I have some MySQL tables (primarily InnoDB and some MyISAM engines) that can only be updated by first truncating and then inserting the data. I have to truncate the data because I have no good way of determining what data may have been removed since the last sync.

My problem is that during this process it is possible that missing data could be presented to the user. Generally, these tables are small so it should complete within a few seconds at the very most. Should I lock the table prior to truncating and unlock after data is re-inserted? If so, how do I go about this? And are there any potential pitfalls to this method?

Here is a proposed example:

```
try {
    $this->db_connection->beginTransaction();
```

```
$this->db_connection->query('LOCK TABLES my_table READ');

$this->db_connection->query('TRUNCATE TABLE my_table');

$this->db_connection->query('INSERT INTO my_table ...');

$this->db_connection->query('UNLOCK TABLES');

$this->db_connection->commit();
```

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    $this->db_connection->rollBack();
    logError('Unhandled Exception: '.$e->getMessage().' in file '.$e->getFile().' on line '.$e->getLine());
}

Comment: Can you not create an index of some sort to know what data is removed?

Comment: You can lock and unlock tables using a query see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/lock-tables.html

Comment: @Machavity, I'm not opposed to that idea, but it sounds like this may be more complex than I really need, but if you have suggestions or an example of how to go about it I'll definitely look into it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, thanks for the link. I've been looking into that and have edited the question with an example of how I think this should be done, but do not have experience with table locking so not real sure of the details.

Comment: You also need to think about any referencial integrity on innodb tables, i.e. if you truncate `table=invoices` it will also delete rows from `table=invoice_lines` so you may need to lock more than just the obvious tables, if you follow my drift.

Comment: Also I would commit before the UNLOCK although that just feels more sensible, it has no basis in any pre-knowledge.